# How can a for-profit prison enterprise cut costs while also maximizing growth potential?

Tags: economy, prison

I, Jefferson Bezonius, run the largest e-commerce business which have penetrated markets in various nations, making me one of the wealthiest men in the world. My company, Amazo, provides a platform in which customers can purchase items online cheaply and have them shipped to their houses in record time. It is known for providing Amazing service by putting its customers first above all others. However, all is not sunshine and rainbows, as it has become burdened with various legal restraints in my pursuit of growth. Workers have threatened to protest or strike unless allowed to unionize, and the government has passed a mandatory minimum wage increase in the name of forcing corporations to share more of the profits. In addition, there are many pesky labor laws That I must abide by, including obligatory safety measures, standardized work shifts and hours, sick leave, etc. All of these issues are cutting into my market share and preventing me from growing my business fast enough, making my shareholders unhappy.

Fortunately, I have discovered a simple solution that can fix all my problems: the prison system. Private prisons have taken over the incarceration of inmates from the state, saving the taxpayers money while making the system more efficient. As prisoners have been stripped of their rights due to their incarceration, I have made signed contracts with these privately run penitentiaries to lease their inmates for them to work in my factories. The prisoners that I purchase on loan are referred to as disposable class (D - class), and would be made up of the types you would expect: murderers, gangsters, illegals, thieves, millennials, etc,. You know, the typical useless dregs of society that produce nothing of value and wouldn't be missed. This provides a free labor force that can take the place of those pesky workers threatening unionization, as well as bypass the traditional labor laws that plague modern businesses today. I have lobbied Congress to pass laws increasing the amount of crimes that one can be incarcerated for, as well as extending the amount of time an inmate can get. This has drastically increased the number of D-class in the prison system, allowing for a potentially larger work force. If these inmates happen to die on the job, the cadaver of the D-class will be dissected and their organs will be sold on the market, ensuring that I maximize my return on investment and that nothing goes to waste.

However, this hasn't been as cost cuttingly effective as I have hoped. In order to get the most work productivity from a D-class, I still have to cover basic expenses such as room and board, as well as food and medical expenses. Guarding the inmates also has to be paid for, as well as arming them, which is not cheap. Ultimately, the number of D-class will always outnumber the guards. In addition to outnumbering their retainers, some of these inmates are actually dangerous and may provoke an uprising, potentially slowing down operations and leading to frequent crackdowns. Also, the men and women of this generation are inherently lazy and prone to make excuses, leading to an unproductive workforce.

I need a business strategy that allows me to cut costs and lower my margins, while also maximizing the growth potential of Amazo as quickly as possible to return value to my shareholders. How can I make this possible?

Comment: Honest question: for what exactly do you want to use your enslaved workforce? Is there a large amount of very-low-skill jobs available in the USA? (You cannot really use forced labor for anything other than very low skill work, at least not without introducing massive changes to the overall political system. Yes, the Nazis did build rockets with forced labor; but that feat required a rather drastic realignment of the entire political system.) (And low-skill jobs imply very low economic productivity, anyway. I cannot see how this scheme can get anything more than a modest profit.)

Comment: Organ donation does not work like that - a person must be on life support at the time of brain death in order for any organs to be viable for transplant.  (Or they can be outright alive in the case of kidney donation.)  Limited tissue donation can occur from a fresh cadaver (eg corneas) but no organs.  The popular cyberpunk image of a body being taken away and then chopped up for parts is medically impossible.

Comment: You also may want to rewrite the sentence "Guarding the inmates also has to be paid for, as well as arming them, which is not cheap."  I'm sure the prisoners like being armed, but it means they can effectively resist being overworked!

Comment: If your company is strictly e-commerce (internet shop), then most of your employees are warehouse, distribution centre, and delivery service workers. Is it really wise to employ inmates in these positions? If you also have some manufacturing (you mention factories), why have them in the USA when abusing the prison system in a 3d world country could be cheaper, easier, and more effective? A global company should think global and not limit itself to a rich country with unreasonable laws.

Comment: PART ONE:  D-Class prisoners would be the worst possible choice. You want A & B class inmates. Presumably B class prisoners are serving lesser but still lengthy sentences than D class prisoners. (I assume A class prisoners are short timers/first offenders. This is for a number of reasons; (1) There are many more of them. Contrary to popular perception murderers/ violent serial offenders make up a far smaller proportion of  the prison population than those imprisoned for property and drug related crimes etc.

Comment: PART TWO: (2) The lesser offenders also have something to gain from co-operating (a reduction in sentences perhaps or other rewards?) The 'lifers' etc don't & are more likely to be disruptive than helpful i.e. constantly trying to escape & or sabotage production. Which raises operating costs. Maximum security infrastructure/guarding is the big cost killer, not food & amenities etc for prisoners, they're cheap by comparison. As is the cost of firearms, cuffs and batons etc. They're not one weeks wages for a prison guard. As described your 'system' will probably lead to riots & arson not profit.

Comment: @Bezonius good job, man, do what u do - employ more robots. Make a factory to sell it to others so as have full cost/profit control for yourself, deversify, anyway you need it for your space things. Good job man, keep it up.

Comment: I **really** dislike your choice of a faux-fictional name for the evil overlord. Is that necessary? Twice I was about to vote to close, twice I decided that it wasn't any one of the prescribed categories.

Answer (score 3):

## Automation

The car industry has already mastered this. It used to be that you needed thousands of workers in a factory to make a few hundred cars per day. Now you can have a factory building thousanda of cars a day with a skeleton crew of just a handful operators.

Robots do not unionize, do not sleep, do not fall sick and do not sue. All they need is electricity and lube, and here and there some spare parts.

Jeff Bezos knows thid and is investing heavily in robotics. In some places Amazon deliveries are made by drones. And in warehouses a lot of the moving around is now done by robots that look like giant roombas. More robots are coming up in the future to replace more humans. I've seen some ostrich shaped ones that can replace humans in even more functions in warehouses, they are able to pick up heavy loads in shelves, carry them and put them in boxes.

Answer (score 2):

**Multiple Exits**

"This is a detention area, you know.  They don't build them with multiple exits."  Princess Leia in [Star Wars IV - A New Hope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(film))

As noted by @Otkin in comments, an e-commerce business' workers are mostly working in warehouses and conducting deliveries.  This may be the *worst possible type of work* for prisoners who may want to escape and/or commit more offences.  It is also the worst possible workforce to have for a business that must be reliable, efficient and quick in order to maintain its customer-centric focus.  (All it takes to kill market share for a very long time is for one delivery driver to commit a violent crime or one warehouse worker to contaminate some consumables or pharmaceuticals.)

The only part of this that might work would be utilising low-risk prisoners who will soon be eligible for parole.  Lock locators around the ankles of the low risk prisoners and gain influence with (aka buy off) the parole board and parole officers so that prisoners know that if they work really well then they have a good chance of making parole.  Don't worry about guards at all, just set the local law enforcement on anyone who escapes - and hope that the "low risk" assessment was correct.  When the prisoners who work best do make parole, employ them, on the very clear understanding that if they try to argue about wages, unionise or do anything else that annoys you then a parole violation will be uncovered and they will go back to prison.

**Legislative lobbying**

Maximising the utility of this segment of the prison population means that slightly different legislative lobbying is required.  You don't care about sentences for high risk (mostly violent) prisoners, as they cannot be safely used in your e-commerce business.  What you want is for low risk prisoners to have slightly longer sentences *but* be eligible for parole and/or home detention earlier, to maximise the amount of time that they can be used as a labour force with minimal rights.  (Home detention is really good, as your costs are reduced to the monitoring of the ankle-locked locators and the possibility of a prisoner being allowed to live with their family is a powerful incentive for good behaviour.)

Remember that workers are not productive until they are trained, so you want to minimise turnover by only starting with the prisoners who will have a lengthy period of work release / parole.

**Unmitigated liabilities**

However, this still leaves the management of the majority of prisoners for the majority of their terms as a conventional business operation to run a prison.  Organ-legging is not a viable option for increasing profit unless you are crossing the line to large-scale premediated murder.  (Contrary to popular belief, organ donation is only possible if a person's body is still "alive" on life support at the time of brain death, which only happens for <1% of deaths normally.)

Short version - think about cutting a deal with prison/s in proximity to your operating areas to get access to their low risk prisoners as a (possibly) cheaper workforce, but many of the prisoners will be unacceptable risks / huge liabilities rather than assets.

Answer (score 2):

#### Why are you worried about these expenses? They're tax deductions! Bill the government.

So currently the government is paying to keep inmates in prisons. The amount they're paying varies wildly by jurisdiction, but in googling I'm seeing values from \$31,000/yr to \$120,000/yr.

Bill the government \$1 less than what they're currently paying to keep those prisoners, and take that money as extra revenue.

The cost of guarding them, feeding them, clothing them, etc become expenses incurred in the production of that income, that you can claim off your tax. By combining the business units together, you can minimize Amazones tax liability from it's ecommerce operation by deducting guard and meal expenses.

You can even deduct "rent" - that floorspace their cell occupies has an opportunity cost if it were used to store pallets. Bit of creative accounting and you can deduct tens of thousands of dollars per inmate per year.

#### And then: Company-town them in after their sentence finishes

Allow inmates to borrow a few thousand dollars from Amazone in return for expenses at the prison store. "Did you want stationary so you can fill out that appeal form? That'll be $15". The condition is that the debt must be repaid before their sentence ends. You can earn money to repay your debt by working on the warehouse floor, but to earn anything notable you need to repeatedly and consistently exceed quotas.

After their sentence ends - the government is no longer paying you for their food, or rent on their cell, or health care, so they end up having to work harder and harder to clear their debt and earn their freedom.

Answer (score 1):

**Unsafe workplaces**

Industrial "accidents" happening to the worse offenders and laziest workers will "motivate" the workforce to improve efficiency.

In the end, nobody wants to be demoted to work in the dog food manufacturing plant with the big mincers and slippery floors.